# Genre de "log" en tant que journal : le ou la ?

Tags: anglais, genre, informatique

Quand j'ai commencé ma carrière en informatique, à la fin des années 90, mes collègues, clients, et moi-même nommions le fichier journal **la** *log*. Sans doute par analogie avec *la* trace, comme on disait à l'époque de la programmation sur machine à calculer scientifique, ou bien par analogie avec *la* bûche, étymologie acceptée pour "log file". Ensuite je me suis expatrié en Australie, puis, au bout d'une dizaine d'années, je me suis mis à retravailler avec des informaticiens Français. Et là, surprise, les plus jeunes employés de différentes entreprises indépendantes disaient alors **le** log. Je ne sais pas quand le fade-out du féminin et le fade-in du masculin se sont produits, mais c'est visiblement au cours de la première décennie des années deux mille.

Ma question : *quel serait le genre le plus approprié* ? Sachant que je m'interroge sur la motivation de l'emploi du masculin : en vertu de quoi **le** log siérait plus : **le** journal ?

Comment: J'ai toujours dis, et depuis les années 90, le log, en élision du terme fichier, le fichier log. donc LE log.

Comment: Pareil, je n'ai jamais dit *une log* mais j'ai pu dire *une ligne* de log. J'ai sinon beaucoup plus souvent employé ce mot au pluriel (*les logs d'erreur*), sauf quand il s'agit de parler du log de un qui vaut zéro bien sûr...

Comment: Ma boîte à l'époque, où l'on disait "la" log : Atos. donc des professionnels de tous horizons, puisque Atos provenait de la fusion de deux autres grandes entreprises.

Comment: Jamais entendu *la log* non plus, mais je pose une hypothèse: les informaticiens "seniors" auraient-ils appris qu'à l'origine, *a log* en anglais est *une* bûche, et auraient utilisé le féminin par analogie avec le genre de la traduction française ?

Comment: Greg : c'est une piste. C'est ce que j'aime à croire secrètement.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'ai toujours entendu cet emprunt qu'au masculin. J'y lis le genre de "journal de bord" et "livre de bord" qui sont les traductions du terme maritime *logbook* abrégé couramment en *log*.

Explication potentielle pour un usage au féminin : rapprocher cela à la "bûche" me paraît tiré par les cheveux - c'est celle qui servait à lester la corde que les marins tiraient derrière leur navire pour en mesurer la vitesse, le *logbook* incluant le relevé régulier de la vitesse du navire mesuré à l'aide de cette corde lestée. Mais cette étymologie est effacée dans le sens actuel du mot *log* en anglais, qui signifie simplement un relevé d'observations chronologiques sans aucune connotation sylvestre.

J'imagine plutôt un usage composé, par exemple "la log file", abrégé en "la log" (au fait dit-on la file pour un fichier ?? Voilà une autre question...). Mais en tout cas peu courant dans mon expérience.